# Parse table of divs on a website. that doesn't follow standard th & tr format

Tags: selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the table of predictions here but https://theanalyst.com/na/2023/08/opta-football-predictions/

However, I  am struggling to parse the divs table.  I find_all("tr") and getting the row data doesnt work as I expect however each table looks sensible in the pase_table function below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse_table(table):
    #struggling here <-

def parse_tables(soup):
    try:
        # Find all tables on the page
        tables = soup.find_all('table')

        # Loop through each table and extract data
        data = []
        for table in tables:
            table.append(parse_table(table))

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred during table parsing: {e}")

def parse_website():
    # Start a virtual display
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
    display.start()

    try:
        # Set Chrome options with the binary location
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'

        # Initialize Chrome driver
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

        # Open the desired URL
        url = 'https://theanalyst.com/na/2023/08/opta-football-predictions/'
        driver.get(url)

        # Wait for the page to load completely (adjust the time as needed)
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)

        # Get the page source after waiting for it to load
        page_source = driver.page_source

        # Parse the page source using BeautifulSoup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')

        # Call the function to parse tables
        parse_tables(soup)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

    finally:
        # Quit the driver and stop the virtual display
        if 'driver' in locals():
            driver.quit()
        display.stop()

# Call the function to parse the website
parse_website()
```

So I tried to parse search for find_all("tr") and iterating through but I am not corectly identifying the fields from here [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tables list is placed in iframe, so to get frame content you should switch to it's context first.

Needed frame is last frame with selector `iframe[src*=predictions]`

Inside frame you should filter for visible tables as far as tables for other dates are rendered with empty content.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://theanalyst.com/na/2023/08/opta-football-predictions/'

driver.get(url)
delay = 10
predictions = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe[src*=predictions]')))

driver.switch_to.frame(predictions[-1])

tables = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class*=match-card-body] table')

visible_tables = [table for table in tables if table.is_displayed()]
for table in visible_tables:
    rows = table.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tr')
    for row in rows:
        print(row.text)
```

Comment: any idea how to identify the button to click on ? for the following day